# Add header to http requests made from within html

Tags: angular, http-headers, httprequest

I have protected my api endpoints by requiring that they carry an authorization token in the request header. The server ensures that this token is present and valid at each endpoint. Everything works fine for requests coming from the client code (Angular 2).

But what about requests coming from the html?

```
...
<img src="api/Videos/{{video.id}}/thumbnail">
...
```

How might I add the authorization header for these requests? This is an Angular 2 app, so there are probably several solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you could create a Service to fetch the needed data (from the HTTP request),

```
 getData() : Observable<Model[]> {
     // ...using get request
     return this.http.get(this.url)
            // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            //...errors if any
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
 }
```

and your model

```
export class Model {
constructor(
    public id: string, 
    public imagePath: string
    //other properties that you might need..
    ){}
```

}

then you only have to bind the src property like

```
 <img class="img-responsive" src="{{model.imagePath}}" style="max-height: 50px;"/>
```

Note that you can add headers to your request like that

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
```

and then

```
return this.http.get(url, {
  headers: headers
});
```